# Filtering through array and displaying it automatically in the view in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm able to post and get data from a database but it only updates the value in the view upon refresh. From what I understand the filter method creates a new array so I don't understand why it's not showing automatically.

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ni1pg

Here's the component:

```
export class TransactionsComponent implements OnInit {
  transactions: Transaction[];
  groceriesList: Transaction[]; 
  transList: Transaction[];

  constructor(private postsService: PostService) {}



  ngOnInit() {
      this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.transactions=posts; 
      this.groceriesList=posts.filter(item => item.category==="Groceries")
      this.transList=posts.filter(item => item.category==="Transportation")

    });
    // this.refreshGroceries()   
    }
```

Here's the html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">

    <ul class="list-group">
      <a 
      class="list-group-item" 
      style="cursor:pointer"
      *ngFor="let transaction of transactions">
    {{ transaction.name }} ({{ transaction.amount }}) - ({{ transaction.category }})</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <h1>Groceries</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <a 
      class="list-group-item" 
      style="cursor:pointer"
      *ngFor="let grocery of groceriesList">
    {{ grocery.name }} ({{ grocery.amount }}) - ({{ grocery.category }})</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <h1>Transportation</h1>
    <ul class="list-group">
      <a 
      class="list-group-item" 
      style="cursor:pointer"
      *ngFor="let item of transList">
    {{ item.name }} ({{ item.amount }}) - ({{ item.category }})</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is that a question?

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to do. for the list to change, you need code that will change the list. and it would need to be triggered by a button or something. I don't see that kind of code in your project.

Comment: @Aravind, yes. The view isn't updating automatically.

Comment: @Rick I'm trying to post and get data from the database and update the view automatically. Post and get work, but not the update.

Comment: add a `console.log(this.groceriesList);` statement to make sure your list is getting populated. in angularJs you needed a $scope.$apply(); to see the changes, but for angular, it should show up automatically.

Answer (score 2):

`this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(...)` will only execute once, it is not going to keep polling the API, so in onCreatePost you need to either call this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe again or add the result of this.postsService.createAndStorePost to the arrays.

**Reloading after post**

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.loadPosts();
}

onCreatePost(postData: Transaction) {
  this.postsService.createAndStorePost(postData.name, postData.amount, postData.category)
    .subscribe(() => this.loadPosts());
}

loadPosts() {
  this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(posts => {
    this.transactions=posts; 
    this.groceriesList=posts.filter(item => item.category==="Groceries");
    this.transList=posts.filter(item => item.category==="Transportation");
  });
}
```

and change createAndStore in post.service.ts

```
createAndStorePost(name: string, amount: number, category: string) {
  const postData: Transaction = {name: name, amount: amount,  category: category}
  return this.http
    .post<{name: string }>(
      'https://budget-dfc78.firebaseio.com/posts.json',
      postData
    );
}
```

**Adding post result to arrays**

```
onCreatePost(postData: Transaction) {
  this.postsService.createAndStorePost(postData.name, postData.amount, postData.category)
    .subscribe(transaction {
      this.transactions.push(transaction);

      if (transaction.category==="Groceries") {
        this.groceriesList.push(transaction);
      }

      if (transaction.category==="Transportation") {
        this.transList.push(transaction);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: The first approach (reloading after post) is throwing ERROR in src/app/transactions/transactions.component.ts(26,8): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: Change the creatAndStore function to return the observable instead of subscribing within the function. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Change the ngOnInit method to below

```
ngOnInit() {
          this.postsService.fetchPosts().subscribe(posts => {
          this.transactions=posts; 
      },
      ()=>{},
      ()=>{
          this.groceriesList=this.transactions.filter(item => item.category==="Groceries")
          this.transList=this.transactions.filter(item => item.category==="Transportation")
    }
});
```